# Getting the right iOS keyboard for an international zipcode field

Tags: ios, html, keyboard

I have a postal code field that can be filled out by users in countries that have alpha numeric postal codes. Most of the time it will be filled out by Americans that only have numeric zip codes. What I'd like to do is have the default keyboard displayed be the numeric keyboard but not the telephone keyboard so international users can swap between the letters and numbers. So far I've tried....

type="tel" this gives me the phone keyboard

type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" this gives me the phone keyboard

type="number" this gives me the numeric keyboard I want but on desktops it adds that number incrementer to the text box.

Does any one have a good way of doing this?

Comment: I re-asked this question, only with much more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425181/iphone-ios-presenting-html-5-keyboard-for-postal-codes