# cordova numeric keypad input

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Sometimes on certain field we need only decimal number to be inserted. How can we get the phone to display numeric keypad instead of normal keyboard to enable user easier enter the numeric input?

Comment: something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425181/iphone-ios-presenting-html-5-keyboard-for-postal-codes)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `type ="number"` on the input tag. *For HTML5*

> `<input type="number">`

Experiment with options for *type* attribute, that are documented [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

NOTE: New HTML5 input types, that are not supported, will just fallback to `type="text"`

Answer (score 1):

For a numeric keyboard, you need to set its type to number

```
      <input type="number"/>
```