# Error input type when using webview to make IOS application

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby on rails website which is designed mobile's view. In this web, I have 2 input: email and zip code which is define input[type=email] and input[type=tel] respectively. I checked this view in Safari browser and 2 above inputs work correctly - it mean the keyboard display @ in email field and numeric keyboard in zip code field. I used this website (or webview exactly) to make IOS webview application, however 2 above inputs is still input[type=text] and the keyboard only display text keyboard. This is html my code:
- email field:

```
<input type="email" name="user_email" id="user_mail" maxlength="300" size="30" >
```

zip code field:

```
<input type="tel" name="zip_code" id="zip_code" maxlength="8" size="10" placeholder="1050001" >
```

What are reasons and solution of this issue? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS webview to display numeric only, you have to have `pattern="[0-9]*"` at the zip code field.

```
<input type="tel" name="zip_code" pattern="[0-9]*" id="zip_code" maxlength="8" size="10" placeholder="1050001">
```

Reference: [iPhone / iOS : Presenting HTML 5 Keyboard for Postal Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425181/iphone-ios-presenting-html-5-keyboard-for-postal-codes)