# Html input type="tel" vs inputmode="tel"

Tags: html, input

Knowing both is used as a hint for mobile browsers, I couldn't find a real doc about the difference between using `<input type="tel">` and `<input inputmode="tel">`. So

- what's the difference?
- which is better to use?
- why duplication if it's the same?

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) doc suggests using the type. But it's still unclear on the explaination.

Comment: Ive tested on https://inputtypes.com/ and inputmode=numeric doesn't show only number keypad on android chrome. So for me seems like type=number is better

Comment: `type='number'` is a bad idea as phone numbers can consist of other characters too, and a number (100034) is an entirely different thing from a phone number (1-800-U-LUV-PIZZA). The keyboards offered for numbers vs phone numbers, by iOS / Android, are different too.

Comment: Sorry but the topic isn't about the numbers but "tel" as in telephone..

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the purpose of the attribute.

`inputmode` defines what kind of input mode the user agent (browser / operating system) should present to the user. Basically what type of keyboard.

`type` is about what type of value is expected, to which the user agent may apply acceptance / validation patterns. That said, the user agent will probably assume a default input mode based on that too.

It's entirely possible, for example, that you don't trust the default input mode or accepted input pattern that is supplied by the user agent. In such a case, `type='text'` is the safest input type, while the `inputmode` is still at your discretion, which you could set to `tel` in this case.

Answer (score -2):

If you want only show the "phone keys" like 0 to 9 and * and #, use

```
<input inputmode="tel">
```

If you want to show a form field with regular keyboard, use

```
<input type="tel">
```

Also see "[Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About inputmode](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inputmode/)".

Comment: On iOS, they appear the same keypad, no regular keyboard

Comment: OK, Apple, grwl ... have a look at [iPhone / iOS : Presenting HTML 5 Keyboard for Postal Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425181/iphone-ios-presenting-html-5-keyboard-for-postal-codes) and [Managing the Keyboard // Apple DEV](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW12)

Comment: I did. Nothing useful that could lead to conclusion